# Partitions order when reading Iceberg table by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-iceberg

I have a large partitioned Iceberg table [ordered by some columns](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-ddl/#alter-table--write-ordered-by). Now I want to scan through some filtered parts of that table using Spark and `toLocalIterator()`, preserving the order.

When my filter condition outputs the data from single partition everything is OK - the rows are ordered as expected.

The problem happens when there are multiple partitions in result - they come to me in random order. Of course I can add `ORDER BY` to my select statement, but that triggers expensive sorting, which is totally unnecessary if I only could explicitly specify the order for partitions.

The question is: how to tell Spark to use that order (or some other order)? Or broader: how to leverage from ordering columns in Iceberg schema?